# Analyze table in R to count nucleotide frequencies

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I have a table of strings, I believe, that I extracted from a text file that contains a list of nucleotides (ex. "AGCTGTCATGCT.....").

Here are the first two rows of the text file to help as an example:

```
AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGCTTCTGAACTGGTTACCTGCCGTGAGTAAATTAAAATTTTATTGACTTAGGTCACTAAATACTTTAAC
```

I need to count every "A" in the sequence by incrementing its variable, a. The same applies for G, C, and T (variables to increment are g, c ,t respectively).

At the end of the "for" loop I want the number of times "A" "G" "C" and "T" nucleotides occurred so I can calculate the dinucleotide frequencies, and hoepfully the transition matrix. My code is below, it doesn't work, it just returns each variable being equal to 0 which is wrong. Please help, thanks!

```
#I saved the newest version to a text file of the nucleotides
dnaseq <- read.table("/My path file/ecoli.txt")
g=0
c=0
a=0
t=0

for(i in dnaseq[[1]]){
    if(i=="A") (inc(a)<-1)
    if(i=="G") (inc(g)<-1)
    if(i=="C") (inc(c)<-1)
    if(i=="T") (inc(t)<-1)
}
a
g
c
t
```

Comment: Could you show the first few lines of `ecoli.txt` (or the starts of those lines if they are too long?)

Comment: Sure, here's the first two rows of the text file:AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC
TTCTGAACTGGTTACCTGCCGTGAGTAAATTAAAATTTTATTGACTTAGGTCACTAAATACTTTAACCAA

Comment: You can edit this into the original post with the `edit` link.

Comment: Is each line a different sequence, or do they all combine together (so that you don't care about the difference between one line and another?) also, are there any non-ACTG characters (e.g. N, or lowercase) and if so do you care about their frequencies?

Comment: The whole text file is just one sequence and they are together. There are not any non-ACTG characters: the code doesn't give any errors the variables are just equal to 0 which is wrong.

Comment: You will not be able to count the dinucleotide frequencies from the single nucleotide frequencies alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get the counts of each nucleotide (or any kind of letter) is to use the `table` and `strsplit` functions. For example:

```
myseq = "AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC"

# split it into a vector of individual characters:
strsplit(myseq, "")[[1]]
#  [1] "A" "G" "C" "T" "T" "T" "T" "C" "A" "T" "T" "C" "T" "G" "A" "C" "T" "G" "C" "A" "A" "C" "G" "G" "G" "C" "A" "A" "T" "A" "T" "G" "T" "C" "T" "C" "T" "G" "T"
# [40] "G" "T" "G" "G" "A" "T" "T" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "G" "A" "G" "T" "G" "T" "C" "T" "G" "A" "T" "A" "G" "C" "A" "G" "C"

# count the frequencies of each
table(strsplit(myseq, "")[[1]])
# A  C  G  T 
# 20 12 17 21
```

Now, if you don't care about the difference between one line and the next (if this is just one long sequence in ecoli.txt) then you want to combine the file into one long string first:

```
table(strsplit(paste(dnaseq[[1]], collapse = ""), "")[[1]])
```

That's the one line solution, but it might be clearer to see it in three lines:

```
combined.seq = paste(dnaseq[[1]], collapse = "")
combined.seq.vector = strsplit(combined.seq, "")
frequencies = table(combined.seq.vector)
```

---

If you're wondering what was wrong with your original code- first, I don't know where the `inc` function comes from (and why it wasn't throwing an error: are you sure `dnaseq[[1]]` has length greater than 0?) but in any case, you weren't iterating over the sequence, you were iterating over the lines. `i` was never going to be a single character like `A` or `T`, it was always going to be a full line.

In any case, the solution with `collapse`, `table` and `strsplit` is both more concise and computationally efficient than a for loop (or a pair of nested for loops, which is what you would need).

Comment: Thank you, what if I wanted to count every 2 nucleotides and their frequencies? ex. "AA, "GC" "TA" etc.

Comment: @JMan if you set up the `combined.seq.vector` as shown above, you can do `paste0(head(combined.seq.vector, -1), tail(combined.seq.vector, -1))` to turn it into a vector of dinucleotides. You can then use `table` on that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code which calls the `str_count` function (that counts the number of occurrences of a fixed text pattern) from the `stringr` package. It should work faster than the other solution which splits the character string into one-letter substrings.

```
require('stringr') # call install.packages('stringr') to download the package first
# read the text file (each text line will be a separate string):
dnaseq <- readLines("path_to_file.txt") 
# merge text lines into one string:
dnaseq <- str_c(dnaseq, collapse="")
# count the number of occurrences of each nucleotide:
sapply(c("A", "G", "C", "T"), function(nuc)
   str_count(dnaseq, fixed(nuc)))
```

Note that this solution may easily br extended to the length > 1 subsequence finding task (just change the search pattern in `sapply()`, e.g. to `as.character(outer(c("A", "G", "C", "T"), c("A", "G", "C", "T"), str_c))`, which generates all pairs of nucleotides).

However, note that detecting *AGA* in *AGAGA* will report only 1 occurrence as `str_count()` does not take overlapping patterns into account.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your nucleotide sequence is in a character vector of length one. If you are looking for the dinucleotide frequencies and a transition matrix, here is one solution:

```
dnaseq <- "AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAG
           CTTCTGAACTGGTTACCTGCCGTGAGTAAATTAAAATTTTATTGACTTAGGTCACTAAATACTTTAAC"

## list of nucleotides
nuc <- c("A","T","G","C")
## all distinct dinucleotides
nuc_comb <- expand.grid(nuc,nuc)
nuc_comb$two <- paste(nuc_comb$Var1, nuc$Var2, sep = "")
   # Var1 Var2 two
# 1     A    A  AA
# 2     T    A  TA
# 3     G    A  GA
# 4     C    A  CA
# 5     A    T  AT
# 6     T    T  TT
# 7     G    T  GT
# 8     C    T  CT
# 9     A    G  AG
# 10    T    G  TG
# 11    G    G  GG
# 12    C    G  CG
# 13    A    C  AC
# 14    T    C  TC
# 15    G    C  GC
# 16    C    C  CC

## Using `vapply` and regular expressions to count dinucleotide sequences:
nuc_comb$freq <- vapply(nuc_comb$two, 
  function(x) length(gregexpr(x, dnaseq, fixed = TRUE)[[1]]), 
  integer(1))
# AA TA GA CA AT TT GT CT AG TG GG CG AC TC GC CC 
# 11 11  7  5  9 12  9 13  7 13  4  2  8  7  5  2

## label and reshape to matrix/table
dinuc_df <- reshape(nuc_comb, direction = "wide", 
  idvar = "Var1", timevar = "Var2", drop = "two")
dinuc_mat <- as.matrix(dinuc_df_wide[-1])
rownames(dinuc_mat) <- colnames(dinuc_mat) <- nuc
   # A  T  G C
# A 11  9  7 8
# T 11 12 13 7
# G  7  9  4 5
# C  5 13  2 2

## get margin proportions for transition matrix 
## probability of moving from nucleotide in row to nucleotide in column)
dinuc_tab <- prop.table(dinuc_mat, 1)
#           A         T          G          C
# A 0.3142857 0.2571429 0.20000000 0.22857143
# T 0.2558140 0.2790698 0.30232558 0.16279070
# G 0.2800000 0.3600000 0.16000000 0.20000000
# C 0.2272727 0.5909091 0.09090909 0.09090909
```